# Equality with rank and dimension of linear map (endomorphirms).

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am desperately looking for a hint !

I have to prove the following equality :

$\forall (u, v) \in \mathscr{L}(E)^2, \mathrm{rg} (v) - \mathrm{rg}(u \circ v) = \dim (\mathrm{Ker} (u) \cap \mathrm{Im} (v))$

($u$ and $v$ are endomorphisms, and $\mathrm{rg}$ is the rank of a linear map (i.e. $\mathrm{rg} (u) = \dim (\mathrm{Im}(u))$)).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite this as $\,\operatorname{rk} v= \operatorname{rk}(u\circ v) +\dim(\ker u\cap\operatorname{im} v)$.

Then note that

- $\operatorname{rk} v= \dim(\operatorname{im} v) $,
- $\operatorname{rk}(u\circ v) =\operatorname{rk}(\left.u_{}\right\rvert_{\operatorname{im} v}) $, and
- $\ker u\cap\operatorname{im} v=\ker(\left.u_{}\right\rvert_{\operatorname{im} v})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !

(Maybe just a typo : on the second item line : is it $\dim (u|_{\mathrm{Im}(v)})$ or $\dim ( \mathrm{Im} (u|_{\mathrm{Im}(v)}))$ ?)

Comment: Yes, bad copy-paste. Thanks for pointing it. Corrected now as a rank.